# Custom Visualforce Related List New Button Does Not Redirect

Tags: redirect, salesforce, visualforce

I created a visualforce page that acts as a related list on the Opportunity.  It displays a checkbox list of Quotes that are related to the opportunity. The visualforce related list has a custom button that calls an apex process, and it also has a button to create a new quote from that related list visualforce page.  The problem is when I click my custom New button (called New Quote), the button does not redirect to the new Quote page as I am trying to redirect.  Instead, it opens my visualforce related list in a new tab.  This is part of the page code:

```
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <div align="center" draggable="false">
             <apex:commandButton value="Apply Quote to Oppty" action="      {!ApplyQuoteToOpp}" />
             <apex:commandButton value="New Quote" action="{!NewQuote}" />
        </div>
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstcheckedquotes}" var="quo">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!quo.selected}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.quotenumber}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Quote Name">
                <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Quote.View, quo.qte.id)}" target="_blank">{!quo.qte.name}</apex:outputLink>    
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.expirationdate}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.totalprice}" />
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.discount__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.createddate}" />
            <apex:column value="{!quo.qte.createdbyid}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

This is the extension controller code that governs the New Quote button:

```
    public PageReference NewQuote()
    {

        Quote newquote;
        Id qid;

        newquote.opportunityid=opp.id;
        insert newquote;

        qid=newquote.id;
        system.debug('newquote id is ' +qid);

        PageReference pageref = ApexPages.currentPage();
        pageref = New PageReference('/' +qid);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref;
    }
```

When the New Quote button is clicked, it opens my visualforce related list in a new tab as shown in the attached picture.  I want it to open the new quote that was just created with a link to the opportunity.  What am I doing wrong?  I am on Spring '18.

[Visualforce related list on Opportunity Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfQV2.png)

[Full Visualforce Page After New Quote button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtnlW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that its the pagref call. First u say that the pagref is the current page and after the call u define it with new
try the folllowing:

```
PageReference pr = Page.<NameOfVFPage>;
pr.getParameters().put('qid', param);
```

Comment: I actually resolved it a different way.  I have posted the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved my issue.  The code is below:

```
    Quote newquote = New Quote();
    Id qid;

    newquote.opportunityid=opp.id;
    newquote.name= 'newquote';
    insert newquote;

    qid=newquote.id;
    //system.debug('newquote id is ' +qid +' and name is ' +newquote.name);

   String baseurl = system.url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
   String redirect = baseurl+'/'+qid;
   //system.debug('baseurl is ' +baseurl );
   //system.debug('redirect is ' +redirect);

    PageReference pr = new PageReference(redirect);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
```